# Mean-reversion for random process

Tags: mean, random-variable, arima, convergence

I moedelled following ARIMA Process which I also smoothed.

> abc1 <- (arima.sim(n = 1400, list(ar = c(0.3, 0.2, 0.15, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1)), sd = sqrt(0.5)))
>   plot(abc1)
>   abc2 <- SMA(abc1, n=360)
>   plot(abc2)

My aim is it to add a component for mean-reversion to describe a business cycle model. Ideas?

thanks, F!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the ARIMA models doesn't fit because of a cyclic component with a known period you can use seasonal differencing to handle the periodic component.  Another possibility is to incorporate a sine wave with the amplitude as a parameter for the model.  If you are not sure of the exact length of the period you can make the frequency component in the sine function a model parameter.  Periods can also be identified by looking at the periodogram of a smoothed version called the spetral density function.